# How to show exception messages in production?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In dev environment play framework is nicely showing exceptions with stacktraces. But when I move it to production it only shows exception id. How to show at least exception message on error page in prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exceptions and show whatever you want :

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

    override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
        InternalServerError(
            views.html.errorPage(ex)
        )
    }
 }
```

Checkout the official [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaGlobal)  and the [default error page!](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/9e967d77bd381217ceb85d5fc01a0dbc2ad444d1/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/error.scala.html)

Comment: Nice! And where can I get default error page so I can tweak it a little?